# How to avoid changing of image and layout position when changing from portrait to landscape mode in android

Tags: android, image, landscape-portrait

I have problem while using lanscape mode in android.How to avoid changing of image position changing from portrait to landscape mode in android.Normally landscape4 and portrait mode is good.If we goes from one mode to another then position of images are changed. Please help me

Comment: How `position of images are changed`? Post your layout code

Comment: Create another Layout for landscape. Put it in \res\layout-land and name it exactly as your portrait layout xml.

Comment: I did (res\layout-land) like this only

Answer (score 1):

The activity in which you are showing image, register that Activity in Android Manifest file as:

```
<activity
     android:name="com.android.YourActivity"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

In this way, it will force the activity to stay in Portrait mode only.

Comment: I think he doesn't want to force one mode. I didn't get that from the question.

Comment: What I got from his question is that, the way he has arranged the images in Portrait mode, all the arrangements gets disturbed when he goes from Portrait to Landscape mode. So he wants to force that activity to only portrait mode.

Comment: `So he wants to force that activity to only portrait mode`. Does he?

Comment: I want both portrait and landscape

Comment: Ok. Can you please elaborate your question?

Answer (score 1):

The orientation changes causes the running activity to restart.The restart behavior is designed to help your application adapt to new configurations by automatically reloading your application with alternative resources that match the new device configuration. Hence resource intensive.
Depending on how you want you app to behave and the device performance you can handle the orientation change(config changes as a whole) in following ways:

- Fixed orientation: If you want your app to have a fixed orientation in landscape or portrait mode. For this you need to set this attribute in the manifest file under the activity tag.

  > ```
  >    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  >    or
  >    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
  > ```
- Handling the Configuration Change Yourself: You can handle the orientation change yourself if your application doesn't need to update resources during a specific configuration change and you have a performance limitation that requires you to avoid the activity restart, then you can declare that your activity handles the configuration change itself, which prevents the system from restarting your activity.
  For this you need to declare this in the manifest file:

  ```
  <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
  ```

  and you need to override the onConfigurationChanged() method of the activity.
  ** use this as the last resort as every thing needs to be handled by you.
- Default behavior: You can let android handle the config changes choosing the alternative resources from the resource folder. You just need to provide these alternate resources for landscape and portrait mode.

Comment: Thank you.i already use android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" but it still not working

Comment: can you upload a snap shot of the present display